# Force Recurring PayFlow Payment

Tags: paypal

Implementing processing to decativate a user when recurring payments dont go through.

The process we are trying to do is as follows:

After 3 failed attempts for recurring payment to go through we need to try 1 more time with a automated force of the payment 1 more time.

So looking at the PayFlow SDK for .NET for a way to used the existing PayFlow Profile to simply real-time try to force the payment.  I find the RecurringPaymentTransaction class. Looks like it would be what we need to use.   It seems that there is more information needed then I have. Really all I want to use is the ProfileId and the payment number that failed.  Dont want to have to retrieve the amount or create an invoice.  Are those properties required? Is there a better way for us to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

It has been some time since I have installed the .NET SDK, but I typically just process the request using the HTTPS method, and just send over the 4 required variables (TRXTYPE, ACTION, ORIGPROFILEID, and PAYMENTNUM).  The amount does not need to be passed over if you are retrying the payment for the original amount.